# Get Element on Scroll using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have been trying to get Element when i scroll . basically my aim is to get Element while scrolling

e.g  i have

```
<div id='ParentDiv' style="overflow-x:auto">
<div id="1" style="height:50px"> 1 <div>
<div id="2" style="height:100px">2</div> 
<div id="3" style="height:20px>3<div>
</div>
```

is there any way to get id of Div when i scroll to element as ids are dynamic

regards

Comment: Please mark one of answer to finishing this discussion.

Comment: none of the answer is correct, so how can i mark it as answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what you are looking for :

```
$("div").on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(id);
})
```

Comment: i need to get it on scroll

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. On `#parent` scroll, `id` of element that is in screen, written in console.

```js
$("#parent").scroll(function() {
    var winHeight = $(this).height();
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    $(".child").each(function(index){ 
        var elemHeight = $(this).height();
        var elementTop = $(this).position().top; 

        if (elementTop < scrollTop + winHeight && scrollTop < elementTop + elemHeight)
           console.log($(this).attr("id"));       
    });
});
```

```css
#parent {
    height: 150px;  
    overflow: auto;
} 

.child {
    height: 300px;
}

#child1 {
    background: red;
}

#child2 {
    background: blue;
}

#child3 {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1" class="child"></div>
    <div id="child2" class="child"></div>
    <div id="child3" class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesnt produce right results check in console .